Passing a list from a controller to a view in ASP.NET Core MVC
I am trying to pass a List from Home controller to an Index View, but when ever I run my program, I get this error

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MVCWebApp.Models.Student]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'MVCWebApp.Models.Student'

Can anyone help me resolve this issue please?
This is Student model class:
public class Student
{
   public int ID { get; private set; }
   public string? Name { get; private set; }
   public string? Gender { get; private set; }
   public string? Branch { get; private set; }
   public char? Section { get; private set; }

   public Student(int id, string name, string gender, string branch, char section)
   {
       ID = id;
       Name = name;
       Gender = gender;
       Branch = branch;
       Section = section;
   }
}//Student

This is the HomeController, I've hard-coded the student data
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IEnumerable<Student> lstStudents = new List<Student>();

    public HomeController()
    {
        lstStudents = new List<Student>()
                          {
                              new Student(101, "James", "Male", "CSE", 'A'),
                              new Student(102, "Smith", "Male", "ETC", 'B'),
                              new Student(103, "David", "Male", "CSE", 'A'),
                              new Student(104, "Sara", "Female", "CSE", 'A'),
                              new Student(105, "Pam", "Female", "ETC", 'B')
                          };
    }

    public ViewResult Index() => View(lstStudents);
}  //HomeController

This is the index view:
@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@model List<Student>

<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Branch</th>
            <th>Section</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if(Model.Any())
        {
            @foreach(Student student in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@student?.ID</td>
                    <td>@student?.Name</td>
                    <td>@student?.Gender</td>
                    <td>@student?.Branch</td>
                    <td>@student?.Section</td>
                </tr>                   
            }
        }
    </tbody>
 </table>
</div>

